# there is an option for premium registeration in filling form but o am confused how i will specify regestration type in my code

Tags: php

```
$reg = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($reg['reg_type']=='Free'){ 
    echo "<h4>Few features are locked for Free members. Please pay via Bank Draft or easypaisa for premium membership and enjoy premium features.</h4>";
} ?>
<a href="AddEducation.php">Add Educational Information</a><br>
//here i have to give registeratin type but how//<?php if($reg['reg_type']=='Premium' && $reg['payment_status']=='paid'){?>
<a href="AddExperinece.php">Add Experience Information</a><br>
<a href="AddSkills.php">Add Skills Information</a><br>
```

[image]
there is an option for premium registeration in filling form but o am confused how i will specify regestration type in my code

Comment: Please explain what you are confused about. This question doesnt make much sense in its current format

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: payment_status in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobsphp\index.php on line 72

Comment: this is the error in execution

Comment: Maybe you didn't query that field? Unfortunately the code is incomplete.

Comment: Please immediately stop using `mysql_` functions; it is time to modernize.

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with **$reg['payment_status']**

$reg['payment_status'] is not identified in the script / not declared / unknown to the script.